# How do I fix the syntax error in my code?

Tags: python

*The  line with two stars on the side is not working, it says syntax error*
It is really frustrating me please help, it should be the line that says **if food == ("1"):**

````
#Python tutorials
import sys# allows the exit function
import time

#Menu
print("************MAIN MENU**************")
time.sleep(1)
choice = input("""
                      A: Add an item
                      B: Delete an Item
                      C : Checkout
                      Q: Quit/Log Out

                      Please enter your choice: """)


#Adding
if choice == "A" or choice =="a":
    print("Choose from following numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12")
    food = int(input("1,12")
        **if food == ("1"):**
               print("You want to add the All day (large) Breakfast")
               time.sleep(0.5)
               print("Add another item?")
               time.sleep (0.5)
               print("To add another item just type the number")
        elif food == ("2"):
            print ("You want to add the All day (small) Breakfast")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Add another item?")
            time.sleep (0.5)
            print("To add another item just type the number") 
elif choice == "B" or choice =="b":
    print("Choose from following numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 ,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12")
elif choice=="C" or choice=="c":
    print ("Are you sure?")
elif choice=="Q" or choice=="q":
    print ("your mom")```
````

Comment: missing closing parenthesis `food = int(input("1,12")` should be `food = int(input("1,12"))` vote to close as typo. A useful tip is that when you have a syntax error and the reported line looks fine, look at the previous line

Comment: Apart from your missing parenthesis, you put `int` inside *food* and then compare it to `string`. It will never be `True`

Comment: Another useful tip is to share all the information you have regarding the error to avoid others having to guess

Answer (score 0):

You should be carefully about parentheses and indentation. Only if you write `:` , you should slide to the right. And you should close every parentheses you opened. Also your food variable is `int` , not `str` . If you compare any `int` and `str` it will be `False`.
This is valid code:

```
if choice == "A" or choice =="a":
    print("Choose from following numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12")
    food = int(input("1,12"))
    if food == 1:
           print("You want to add the All day (large) Breakfast")
           time.sleep(0.5)
           print("Add another item?")
           time.sleep (0.5)
           print("To add another item just type the number")
    elif food == 2:
        print ("You want to add the All day (small) Breakfast")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Add another item?")
        time.sleep (0.5)
        print("To add another item just type the number") 
elif choice == "B" or choice =="b":
    print("Choose from following numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 ,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12")
elif choice=="C" or choice=="c":
    print ("Are you sure?")
elif choice=="Q" or choice=="q":
    print ("your mom")
```